# SQL Server Log File Viewer Fails

Tags: sql-job

We have about 100 Automatic Tasks in SQL Server, and for about the past 3 days a few of them have been failing.  Is it possible with the log viewer to know which one has been failing?  The log only shows

```
Message [298] SQL Server Error: 15404, Could not obtain information about Windows NT group/user [Removed User], error code 0x534 [SQL STATE 42000] (ConnIsLoginSysAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click on SQL Server Agent -- then double click the Job Activity Monitor.  From here you can view more information and see which actual process is failing.